# Safe to purge config of Debian MySQL server after installing official deb?

Tags: mysql, debian, package-management

Can anyone tell me if it is safe to do an apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5 in Debian after removing mysql-server-5.5 and installing mysql-server via the deb-Package officially provided by MySQL? Do I risk it removing the configs being used by mysql-server? Current state is:

```
ii  mysql-community-server         5.6.25-1debian7
ii  mysql-server                   5.6.25-1debian7
rc  mysql-server-5.5               5.5.39-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `purge` action on an already removed package by definition will try to remove the configuration files provided by that package.

You have installed a package from two different providers that most probably define the same `conffiles`. Find out which are these by issuing:

```
# dpkg-query --showformat='${Conffiles}\n' --show mysql-server
```

for installed packages, and/or by inspecting the contents of

```
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.conffiles
```

for removed packages, provided you haven't cleaned the cache.

You could also try:

```
# dpkg --dry-run --purge mysql-server
```

To see what would happen.

If you really can't live with that `rc` status on the `mysql-server-5.5` package, backup your configuration files, purge the package and restore the configuration files.